# split a string into letter component and number component when not all components have letters

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I searched stackoverflow and couldn't find the answer. Sorry if this has been asked ...

I have a string with numbers and some numbers have letters ...

```
x = c("1", "12", "14A", "12B", "6")
```

I want to separate the number component to get 2 separate columns, 1 with numbers and 1 with the letters ...

```
x = c(1, 12, 14, 12, 6)
y = c(NA, NA, "A", "B", NA)
```

would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why does the 6 at the end stay? Try `gsub('\\D+', '', x)` and `gsub('\\d+', '', x)`

Comment: My first intuition was after using regex to use `parse_number` (which works) and `parse_character` (which unfortunately does not work) both from `readr` package. See: <https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/920>. It would be cool if `parse_character`  could parse only character text,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr`'s function `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(x) %>%
  extract(x, into = c("x","y"), regex = "(\\d+)([A-Z]+)?")
   x y
1  1  
2 12  
3 14 A
4 12 B
5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract` from `stringr` we can try:

```r
library(stringr)

y <- str_extract(x, "\\D+")
x <- str_extract(x, "\\d+")
```